# Filtering virtuoso results in the next execution

Tags: filter, sparql, virtuoso

I run a SPARQL query on Virtuoso (via code) and I receive some results.
I want to filter these results in the next execution.

Are these results stored somewhere on virtuoso for the next execution?

Comment: not sure what you asking, but the query result is just the final result. For `SELECT` this is nothing more than a collection of bindings aka rows. Nothing is stored such that you can refer to this in the following query execution. What kind of query are you talking about? `SELECT` or `CONSTRUCT`? Also why can't you use a subquery to work on the result of the first query? Maybe you can share a concrete example?

Comment: I am referring to SELECT queries. That was my question.. if the results are stored somewhere on virtuoso for the next execution. I want to build a faceted search system on RDF data, so I was wondering if I could filter the results (on each click) immediately on virtuoso.

Comment: besides common caching I doubt there is anything stored in the triple store. But the caching might already be good enough although I know that faceted search can lead to complex queries - we did some experiments in that area as well. Computing the facets as well as their facet value counts can be expensive for sure

Comment: It's worth noting that we have already produced a Faceted browser [for Virtuoso Enterprise 8.3](http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/vad-packages/8.3/fct_dav.vad) and [for Open Source 7.2](http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/vad-vos-packages/7.2/fct_dav.vad). If that is unsatisfactory, please take care that you are not working on an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), and then try to [improve your question, so we can better help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).